# How to change when value get selected

Tags: javascript, selectedvalue

I want to change the result if users selected different option. The result is a table that i get from db

```
<select name="categories" id="categories" onchange="admSelectCheck(this);" class="form-control">
<option >Tabel</option>
<option value="t_sediam">Tabel Sedia</option>
<option value="t_brg">Tabel Barang</option>     
</select>
```

This JS

```
function admSelectCheck(nameSelect)
{
    console.log(nameSelect);
    if(nameSelect){
        admOptionValue = document.getElementById("categories").value;
        if(admOptionValue == "t_sediam"){
            document.getElementById("admDivCheck").style.display = "block";
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById("admDivCheck").style.display = "none";
        }
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById("admDivCheck").style.display = "none";
    }


    console.log(nameSelect);
    if(nameSelect){
        admOptionValue = document.getElementById("categories").value;
        if(admOptionValue == "t_brg"){
            document.getElementById("tbarang").style.display = "block";
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById("tbarang").style.display = "none";
        }
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById("tbarang").style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>
```

And this is the triggered

```
<div id="admDivCheck" style="display:none;">
<?php echo"A"; ?>

<div id="tbarang" style="display:none;">
<?php echo"B"; ?>
```

I expected the output when t_sediam selected, the output is A. And t_brg selected, the output is B

Comment: Why bother with `document.getElementById("categories")`, you already have a reference to the `<select>` with `nameSelect`. Also, you've explained what you expect but not what actually happens

Comment: @Phil the result is when i choose t_sediam, it will A B. But if i choose t_brg, no result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a different approach and uses event delegation. Which is ideal for data based scenarios.

```js
const showData = (showID) => {
  // Hide evenrything
  document.querySelectorAll('.displayData').forEach(d => d.style.display = 'none');
  
  const showEl = document.querySelector(`#${showID}`);
  if(showEl) showEl.style.display = 'block';
}

document.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
  if(e.target.matches('#categories')) {
    switch(e.target.value) {
      case 't_sediam':
        showData('admDivCheck');
        break;
      case 't_brg':
        showData('tbarang');
        break;
      default:
        showData();
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.displayData {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<select name="categories" id="categories" class="form-control">
<option >Tabel</option>
<option value="t_sediam">Tabel Sedia</option>
<option value="t_brg">Tabel Barang</option>     
</select>

<div id="admDivCheck" class="displayData">
   <p>HERE IS SOME DATA</p>
</div>


<div id="tbarang" class="displayData">
  <p>Here is DIFFERENT Data</p>
</div>
```

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer. And yes your right as i said in the first The result is a table that i get from db. But i didnt copy all of that into my question. Anyway, its still not working in my code.  Undefined variable: database. I already define database, its working in my code before, but the result, it wasnt my expect

Comment: sorry, when i using your code. the answer is, if i choose t_sediam, showing A and B. If i choose t_brg, showing blank

Comment: Oh, easy to fix. Hang on`

Comment: no, i recommend your answer before this. i mean, my expect result is if i choose t_sediam, showing A. if i choose t_brg showing B. Im using your code before you edited, its correct in here. but it still wrong in my code. You can change again the answer like before, and i will get you as correct

Comment: Ok, I have gone back to original.

Answer (score 0):

there is more simple to do:

```js
document.getElementById('categories').onchange = function() 
{
  document.getElementById('admDivCheck').style.display =  (this.value=='t_sediam') ? "block" : "none";
  document.getElementById('tbarang').style.display     =  (this.value=='t_brg') ? "block" : "none";
}
```

```html
<select name="categories" id="categories"  class="form-control">
  <option >Tabel</option>
  <option value="t_sediam">Tabel Sedia</option>
  <option value="t_brg">Tabel Barang</option>     
</select>

<div id="admDivCheck" style="display:none;">A</div>
<div id="tbarang"     style="display:none;">B</div>
```

I guess if you want to factorize the possibilities ?

```js
const
  SelCategorie = document.getElementById('categories'),
  elmDisplay   = document.querySelectorAll('.ClassTabels');


SelCategorie.onchange = function() 
{
  for (let i = 0; i < elmDisplay.length; i++ )
  {
    elmDisplay[i].style.display = (elmDisplay[i].id === this.value ) ? 'block' : 'none';
  }
}
```

```css
.ClassTabels {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<select name="categories" id="categories"  class="form-control">
  <option >Tabel</option>
  <option value="admDivCheck">Tabel Sedia</option>
  <option value="tbarang">Tabel Barang</option>     
  <option value="truc">Tabel truc</option>     
  <option value="bidule">Tabel bidule</option>     
</select>


<div id="admDivCheck" class="ClassTabels">A</div>
<div id="tbarang"     class="ClassTabels">B</div>
<div id="truc"        class="ClassTabels">C</div>
<div id="bidule"      class="ClassTabels">D</div>
```

?

Comment: thanks for your answer. when i using your code. the answer is, if i choose t_sediam, showing A and B. If i choose t_brg, showing blank. I still didnt know whats wrong. Anyway, i make the result from table in database (its just not simple ABCD).